# Read git label in version format on Windows

Tags: batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux, awk

I have the following bash script which read the last label from git which is in version format (1.2.3.4).

```
 git tag --sort=-refname | awk 'match($0, /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)' | head -n 1
```

I am looking for an alternative for Windows 11 either by replacing awk by something or wrapping it some call to Ubuntu subsystem.

Comment: Aren't you just using `awk` as fancy `grep`? That should be trivial to replace. // Also, "Windows 11" is not a shell. Do you perhaps want to use PowerShell?